# Generate SHA-2 CSR in Plesk

Tags: security-certificate, plesk

Plesk can be used to generate CSR's for SSL certificates but uses SHA-1 as the hash by default. Browsers will soon prefer SHA-2 certificates, so I'd like to start using that for CSR hashing.

How can I generate CSR's using SHA-2 (i.e. with what would be the `-sha256` flag in OpenSSL) using Plesk?

Comment: The SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384 and SHA-512 functions are colloquially known as "SHA-2", so "SHA-2" is not one function, but a family of four hash functions. Source: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2827883/1892635) so is there an option to use 224, 256 384 or 512? as these are SHA-2 compatible hashs

Comment: That's pretty much my question exactly.